# Jersey/jetty response succeeds in Postman but fails to serialize in browser

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, jetty

I have a webservice with a healthcheck endpoint -- this endpoint essentially returns 200 with an empty body assuming nothing is failing too badly within the service. I've noticed, though, that when I use a browser to access the healthcheck endpoint, it fails. I get the following message:

```
A message body writer for Java class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject, and Java type class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
```

Any idea what's causing this? I figured a GET was a GET.

Comment: Add `@Produces` annotation on your resources methods, and set appropriate `Accept` headers on the client. This is how it works. If you don't do these things then you are at the mercy of the server/client implementations and what they feel is right or whatever is default behavior.

Comment: Could you add your class method code ?